# string memory[3] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes32[] storage ref

Tags: arrays, string, memory, bytes32, data-types

I have the following (array of bytes32 types):

```
bytes32[] public allTokenSymbols = ["0x4554480000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0x4c54430000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0x5852500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"];
```

This gives the following error:

> string memory[3] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type
>   bytes32[] storage ref

How should this be done? I want the array to contain the bytes32 of "ETH", "LTC" and "XRP".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error makes sense... on the right-hand side of the assignment, you have an array of strings, each of which is too large to fit into a `bytes32` anyway. (Each string is 66 characters long.)

Given your intention, which is store the representation of "ETH", "LTC", and "XRP," I believe this code does what you want:

```
bytes32[] public allTokenSymbols = [
        bytes32(0x4554480000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000),
        bytes32(0x4c54430000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000),
        bytes32(0x5852500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)];
```

Note that I'm using hexadecimal numbers instead of strings, and I'm explicitly converting each to a `bytes32`.